Can variables NOT independent of the treatment variable be profitably used for covariate-adjusted estimation of the treatment variable?
My objective is to minimize bias / variance with respect to the estimate of T's (the treatment variable) effect on Y. Let's say that I have a covariate (X) that is extremely predictive of Y. Under ideal circumstances where  ⊥ T, I can implement the model $Y \sim \alpha + \beta_TT + \beta_XX$ (left) and achieve substantial reduction in the standard error of $\beta_T$.
Unfortunately, I cannot assume  ⊥ T and so I am in the scenario on the right. I am trying to confirm if there is any way that X can be profitably incorporated into the model specification to reduce bias / variance with respect to the estimate of the treatment effect. I appreciate that with X and T being correlated, the amount of useful information being communicated by X is going to smaller than if  ⊥ T was true. However, I've been told that with X and T being correlated, there is literally no benefit to including X in the model (assuming our sole coefficient estimate of interest is $\beta_T$).
Is this true - that outside of  ⊥ T, X is useless to us in understanding $T \rightarrow Y$? If so, why? Thank you for the clarification!


$X$ being strongly predictive of $Y$ might also be because $Y \to X$, and also might be because $U\to Y$ and $U\to X$ (regardless of whether $T \to X$ and/or $T \to Y$).

Thanks Alexis. So in this case Y and X are temporally distinct (Y necessarily occurs after X). I take it that U denotes some unknown confounder? That is possible, but we have pretty firm historical reasons to assume that →. To make this more concrete, let's say that Y is the revenue of an order post-fulfillment, X is the monetary value of the items in the basket upon order creation, and T is some treatment influencing how soon the order can be delivered to the customer.

The answer to your question then heavily depends on whether $T \leftarrow X$ or $T \rightarrow X$. If $T \rightarrow X$, $T$ causes $X$ and adjusting for $X$ in any way induces collider stratification bias, so you should leave it alone. If $T \leftarrow X$, $T$ is a confounder, and not adjusting for it leads to bias. Regardless of bias, I would expect that including $X$ in a regression increases precision (except for in weird pathological cases).

Sorry - meant to write $X$ is a confounder if $T \leftarrow X$.

Thanks @Malik !
